# Identify negative values in Collection using blue prism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

[I have one collection named "Total Amount' and having column named "Amount", so i am fetching some amounts from one application and putting them into above collection under same mentioned column hence there are some negative amounts exists into it. So ideally my robot should recognize the negative amount under "Amount" column and if exists, should stop the bot.

Comment: Why not just utilize a loop and a decision stage? When a value is < 0, tie the result to an Exception stage and allow the Exception to terminate the process.

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me whether you want to loop through the 'Total Amount' collection and filter the negative amounts out of there, or skip appending negative amounts to the collection when you're filling it. 
Also it's not clear why you would want to stop the robot if you can just remove the negative values from the collection.

What I would suggest is to use the 'Filter Collection' action in the 'Utility - Collection Manipulation' object.
This action basically checks every item in the collection and matches it to your filter query (in this case "Amount < 0"). 
If the result is True, it will be put into the output collection, if not, if will be omitted.

Another way of doing it, is to loop through the collection using a loop and program the action you want to take with a decision stage when you come across a negative number like Esqew already said in his/her comment.

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

You can `Filter` the collection to check if there is negative values available in specific column. The `Filter` action under `Utility - Collection Manipulation` will allow you to save filtered data into in one more collection. Check the count of generated collection if it is greater than zero then the collection is having negative values else collection does not hold any negative value.

To Filter the collection please check the below screen shot: [image]